# Batch payment in magento

Tags: customer, php, payment, sales, authorize.net

I am developing a magento store where customer places the order without payment. The payment is done after some duration on batch i.e all orders during that time interval should be paid automatically by cron job.

For credit card storage, I am thinking of Authorize.net CIM.

Is it possible to do so? How can I achieve this?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your payment method, it is possible to set a authorization after the order is placed instead of a capture.
For the credit card payment methods I know this is possible, don't know if this applies to Authorize.net CIM.

So you will have the authorized orders then and can do the capture where the invoice will be payed with a batch job.